# Firefox downloads SVG sprite sheet hundreds of times

Tags: firefox, svg, sprite-sheet

I have an SVG sprite sheet which uses `<view>` tags to identify each sprite. To show a sprite you set the `img src` to the spritesheet plus the sprite name as a fragment identifer, like this:

```html
<img src="sprites.svg#coffee" width="60" height="63" />
```

I have a page with a preview of each sprite, so there's hundreds of these tags on the page. When I view this page in Chrome, it downloads the SVG file once. When I view it in Firefox, however, the file seems to get downloaded once for each `<img>` tag, so it gets 2MB of data instead of 9k gzipped. Even if I have the file in the browser cache, it seems that *one* of the requests hits the cache, and the remainder of them ignore it and fetch from the server.

Is there a cache header or tag I should know about to prevent this from happening? Alternately, is this a bug in Firefox? The only one I've found is [497665](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=497665), but that was resolved fixed 8 years ago.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1121693

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, that's exactly the bug report I was struggling to find. If you make it an answer I'll mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: If I did that it would be a link only answer. Those are not permitted.

Comment: @RobertLongson Fair enough, though I'd have thought "this is a known bug in Firefox, see here for details" would cover it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a very old bug that is still around for 9 years...

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1027106
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1121693

One of the [comments](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1027106#c16) mentions a possible workaround:

> Firefox only makes one request, if you use an SVG  element instead of an  or CSS background-image. That is, replace this HTML:
>
> ```
> <img src="sprite.svg#foo">
> ```
>
> with this embedded SVG:
>
> ```
> <svg><use xlink:href="sprite.svg#foo"/></svg>
> ```
>
> (Note the closing “/>” on the !)

Comment: But you will also need to rebuild your spritesheet svg since `<view>` references cant't be used for `<use>` elements. So you need to to give each icon an ID or warp it in a `<symbol>`